# How to install or use Ubuntu server minimal img file with KVM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, linux-kvm

Ubuntu has these minimal server images [here](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/bionic/release/) and I downloaded the `ubuntu-18.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64.img` image. However, it is not quite clear to me as to how this image is to be used with KVM. Ubuntu's own website doesn't seem to offer much information in this regard.

My aim was to create a 3-4 node cluster of VMs on a dedicated bridge network for testing some proprietary application. The VMs would use Ubuntu as the host OS. I am using KVM on an Ubuntu MATE 20.04 host with liquorix kernel. I am pretty sure that KVM setup on my machine works well, as I have used Minikube with kvm2 driver without issues.

My understanding of the downloaded image file is that it is sort of a live-boot image, although not clear as to how to add dedicated storage to it, to create a VM specific filesystem s.t. VM can boot from it.

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding of the downloaded image file is that it is sort of a live-boot image, although not clear as to how to add dedicated storage to it, to create a VM specific filesystem s.t. VM can boot from it.

Looks like it **already is** a VM filesystem image. Point Qemu at the file as the VM's system disk and it should boot.

(It's not a "live boot" image in the sense of liveCDs/liveUSBs; an .img file could just as well contain an ordinary OS installation without any of the usual "live" SquashFS constructions.)

In fact, despite having the `.img` file extension (typically used for "raw" disk images), the file contains a virtual disk in the special QCOW2 format used by Qemu – it isn't a raw 1:1 image like .img and .iso files tend to be.

Similar to VHD/VMDK/VDI formats used by other software, QCOW2 is a "dynamically allocated" image format which omits free space – even though the file is only 190 MB, the actual capacity of the virtual disk is 2.4 GB. (You could probably use `qemu-img` or other tools to grow it further.)

Comment: Thanks. That explanation helps. I found that Ubuntu expects the tools mentioned here to used: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/virtualization-uvt